# How to fill area between curve and origin edge with colormap?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a data with coordinates **X,Y** similar to a Vertical Sine function,  I want to fill the area between left edge and the curve generated using variable color with `colormap` on `matplot`, changes in color whith **X** value as the image (From Blue to Red). I've tried and get this result where start point and final point are conected by a line. I need to fill the left area.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

#Data
y=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
x=np.sin(y)*y+2
    
#Set Array
xx=np.asarray(x)
yy=np.asarray(y)
    
path = Path(np.array([xx,yy]).transpose())
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)
    
im = plt.imshow(xx.reshape(yy.size,1),  cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm,interpolation="nearest",
                    origin='left',extent=[-5,10,0,10],aspect="auto", clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
im.set_clip_path(patch)
```

[image: Plot 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add two additional points lying on the y-axis to create the desired shape:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

y = np.linspace(0, 10, 200)
x = np.sin(y) * y + 2

path = Path(np.array([np.append(x, [-5, -5]), np.append(y, [y[-1], y[0]])]).T)
patch = PathPatch(path, facecolor='none')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

im = plt.imshow(x.reshape(y.size, 1), cmap=plt.cm.coolwarm, interpolation="nearest",
                origin='lower', extent=[-5, 10, 0, 10], aspect="auto", clip_path=patch, clip_on=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]